# Karate framework's special tags @env/@envnot do not consider env value from karate-config.js

Tags: karate

I have a karate feature file as below -

```
Feature: Feature file 

@env=dev
Scenario: runs only when karate.env is 'dev'
* print 'karate.env is:', env

@envnot=perf,prod
Scenario: never runs in perf or prod
* print 'karate.env is:', env
```

And setting env value in karate-config.js as below -

```
var env = karate.env; // get system property 'karate.env'
karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);
if (!env) {
 env = 'dev';
}
karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);
```

But when executing from feature file or runner, it takes karate.env as null unless we run via the command line.

```
09:15:22.988 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: null 
09:15:22.988 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: dev 
09:15:23.019 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] karate.env is: dev
```

But running from the command line (mvn test "-Dkarate.env=dev") it works -

```
09:16:55.118 karate.env system property was: dev 
09:16:55.133 karate.env system property was: dev 
09:16:55.165 [print] karate.env is: dev
```

Should not scenarios be picked based on the env value instead of "karate.env"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. You cannot modify `karate.env` once you have kicked off your test suite.

The example you have used for `karate-config.js` is just a convenience to set a local variable called `env` that can be used *within* the JS block. It does not live beyond `karate-config.js`.

Comment: Got it. So to utilize @env/@envnot tags, the command line is the only way. I want to bring one more point to your notice that switching environment command mentioned in GitHub doc is mvn test -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=e2e" which does not work. An actual working command is mvn test "-Dkarate.env=e2e". Can you please confirm it?

Comment: @AMODMAHAJAN to be honest the command line behaves in very different ways depending on maven version and os type / version, and I myself get confused :(